# Select by attributes from a series of feature classes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have 16 feature classes. What I want to do is to select by attributes each feature class using this statement:

```
    "Shape_Area" < 1100
```

Is there a way to do this by batch using arcpy or arcpy.mapping? I can't find the right module for "Select by Attributes".

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[SelectLayerByAttribute_management](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000071000000) is available in arcpy. You may need to [make a feature layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) if you're not in a mapping session. From the second example at the link:

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("lyr", "SUBSET_SELECTION", ' "population" > 10000 ')
```